# Shipping GKE container logs to memorystore

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine, fluent-bit

I have a GKE cluster which has some applications running. Those application log to stdout for performance reasons. I know GKE comes with fluentbit for logging. I was wondering if there is a way to get the application logs to a memorystore for redis instance that I am running. My question is because fluentbit doesn't come with a redis output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess with **fluentbit** you have to use a custom **plugin** to push to Redis.

**Memorystore** is for **caching** not for **logging** **Big query** would be better incase planning for **analytics** or **search**.

You can use this custom plugin : https://github.com/majst01/fluent-bit-go-redis-output in that case you have to deploy your own **Deamonset** of **Fluentbit**.

If you can't use the Fluentbit custom plugin workaround is to go with **Storage bucket** & **pub/Sub**.

Create custom **user sink** for logs and push to **Bucket** or **Pub/Sub** as per need and from there parse/format and push to **Memory store** Use CloudRun/Function based need batch process or Scheduled job.

With Fluentbit also you can push to GCP **pubsub** with some record transformation if required to logs in **JSON** and using custom [plugin](https://github.com/mdoi/fluent-plugin-gcloud-pubsub).

Comment: Yes, memorystore will be used as a cache for our main logging platform. probably gonna use the custom plugin. Thanks for the information